# Fragment not going to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application i have used fragments with one activity.I have created a method which will call new fragments.The method works fine,but when ever i press back button my app closes, even though i have put fragments in the back stack.Please  help me out.

Code

```
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {

        try {
            String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
            String fragmentTag = backStateName;


            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
//            boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);
            if (manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment, fragmentTag);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                if (addToBackStack) {
                    ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                } else {
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                }
                ft.commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to pop fragment in onBackPressed() method...

Comment: Y do i need to pop onBackPressed(),cant it just directly go to previous fragment from the stack

Comment: `boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);`this is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
EditProfileFragment mEditProfileFragment = new EditProfileFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    mEditProfileFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(MyProfileFragment.class
                    .getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Give your old fragment name means when you press back that Fragment will open

I am not able see your whole code so is your fragment is the parent fragment?

Comment: I have edit the code and please use the same it will definitely work. I am using it..

Comment: No need to use of this function

popBackStackImmediate();

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling activity back press? like below code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (1 < count)
    {       
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();          
    }
}
```